# Regular Expression Processing HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to replace all the HTML tags (e.g. `<p>`, `<img>`, etc.) in a web page source code, but I want to keep `<br>` and `<br/>`. I have tried:

```
re.sub(r'<[^>]+?>', u'', html, flags=re.I)
```

This only achieves the first goal, but it cannot keep `<br>` or `<br/>`. `r'<[^>br]+?>'` wont achieve the goal either.

What is the correct regular expression?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for manipulating HTML - HTML **is not** a regular language. Use an HTML parser. ([Amusing version.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761))

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know you are refering to BeautifulSoup etc. But I do not want to install another plugin for this simple problem.

Comment: There is a parser in the standard library, too: [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Comment: Will come a day when people will stop trying to unscrew a bolt with a hammer (aka parse html with regex)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you recheck your answer? Still all the tags including `<br>` are removed. Is this negative look ahead correct?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, probably around the same time they stop using [double-clawed hammers](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/)

Comment: @AvinashRaj you include an extra `<` inside the brace before `br`. It should be something like this: `<((?!br).)*>`

Comment: I have the correct answer to the other question you asked, which you deleted for some reason. `re.sub(r"((<br\/?>)+)", "<br>", html, flags=re.I|re.UNICODE)` The problem you had was that you had missed out the `flags` keyword, so it was taking `re.I|re.UNICODE` as the `count` kwarg, limiting it to only the first 33 replacements - which was making it look like nothing was happening, because you were only looking at the last line of the input text. I answered here because there's no way to message you the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<((?!\bbr\b).)*?>
```

This should work for your case.The negative lookahead will ensure `<br>` is not picked.

Edit:

```
<(?:(?!\bbr\/?(?=>)).)*?>
```

Try this if you have such absurd things. `<a href="http://host.domain.tld/br">`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/57

Comment: This wont work <((?!<br>|<\/br>)[^>])+?>. Some other tags are kept.

Comment: Still all the tags (including `<br>`) are removed. Is this negative lookahead correct.

Comment: you seem to make a tiny mistake. This works: `<((?!br)[^>])+?>` you include an extra `<` before `br` inside the brace. Is it right?

Comment: Why do you include the `|\/br`? There are only three versions of `br`: `<br>, <br/>, <br />`

Comment: you better use `The negative lookahead` instead of `The lookahead` in your answer, so newbies wont be confused. Just my humble suggestion. The lookahead is one of the most difficule parts in regex.

Comment: @vks Hi what is the `?:` in `<(?:(?!\bbr\/?(?=>)).)*?>`? What does it do?

Comment: @JamesKing `?:` means non capturing group.So if you do a `findall` it will give the whole string as by default `findall` returns only captured group.Or if you use `match` if wont be stroed in `match.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The below regex with negative lookahead assertion would work.

```
<(?!br\/?>)[^<>]*>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zK8jF5/2)